# I split a large Json file to more correctly edit the information. Now that I edit it, how can I merge them back in php?

Tags: php, json, foreach, merge, glob

I had a master Json that I split into individual files to more accurately/correctly edit the information. I did my edits and now would like to combine them back into one master json in php. The current way I have set up is by globing the jsons, then doing a foreach and concatenating but I seem to be having trouble with the concatenation. I tried array_merge_recursive and at first ended up with only one small json with the values set to null and the second time I got one set of keys, each with the value being the whole json repeated over and over again. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
I have one master json that looks something like this -

```
"HELLO": {
    "title": "Hello",
    "elang": "English",
    "abbr": "HLLO",
},
"WORLD": {
    "title": "World",
    "elang": "English",
    "abbr": "WLRD",
},
```

I made each json into it's own file accordingly by doing this -

```
$part2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('../json/Master2.json'), true);
    foreach ($part2 as $keyp3 => $valuep3) {
        file_put_contents("../json/individual/$keyp3.json", json_encode($valuep3, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
    }
```

After I separated them, I ran a glob and edited specific lines to get the info placed that I want. Below is the code I was advised to use but it isn't outputing the data correctly, nor all of the data I have:

```
$final = [];
foreach ($indJson as $keyp5 => $valuep5) {
    $indV = json_decode(file_get_contents("$valuep5"), true);
    foreach ($indV as $key52 => $value52) {
        $final[$key52] = array_merge_recursive(json_decode(file_get_contents("$valuep5"), true), $final);
    }
file_put_contents('../json/FINISHED.json', json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}
```

Comment: when you split the file up did you do it using php/javascript or just some text editor? Is each of the split files valid json in itself or did you just copy chunks out of the file? Did any of your edits break the json with stuff like quotes, colons or braces?

Comment: you said that you split the string up and then edited it again in php.  If this is the case, you could re-encode the string back to JSON so long as it is an array using something like `json_encode($object)`

Comment: Show what you have tried, then we can address your question more adequately

Comment: @JuanMendes I edited the original post to show the code I was working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$indJson` is a map where they key is the master JSON property name and the value is the filename containing the inner JSON, here's what your code should look like;

```
$final = [];
// For each file
foreach ($indJson as $keyp5 => $valuep5) {
    // Get the content of each file as an array
    $indV = json_decode(file_get_contents("$valuep5"), true);
    // Add that inner array to the final array
    $final[$keyp5] = $indV;
}
// After you finish iterating, then you can write out the master file
file_put_contents('../json/FINISHED.json', json_encode($final, 
        JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

**Suggestions for the future**

- Use more meaningful variables names, `$keyp5` is kind of cryptic, specially as someone on SO tried to quickly look at your code and make sense of it.
- Do some debugging on your own, print out the output of `$final` each time through the iteration

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Thanks for the advice too, I'm relatively new to all of this so that helps!

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a transport format.  You really shouldn't be splicing it as strings.

Ideally, you will parse each separate JSON file, assemble your object like you would any other object, and then serialize it as fresh clean JSON.

Comment: I think that the OP is doing that. They mention `array_merge_recursive` which means they already parsed the JSON into an array?